# Interesting logic puzzle grid problem

Tags: logic-grid

Here is a very challenging logic deduction puzzle

[image]

This is not for a graded homework assignment, however it was given to me by a professor for fun. If you post an answer, please discuss how you reached your solution. The questions are very interesting and quite challenging!

I've posted my progress in an answer below.

Comment: If it is not a puzzle that you yourself have written, we like to see some effort put into solving it. Please let us know how far you've gotten and specifically where you're having trouble. I feel the need to repeat myself and link this [tutorial](http://logic-puzzles.org/how-to-solve-a-logic-puzzle.php).  I would also like to inform you that your earlier comment has broken RULE #1 on this site: BE NICE. You should not take criticism personally and should not react by attacking the person doing the criticizing. That is what this site is for.

Comment: As a reminder, that has already been stated - please remember to **[Be Nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)**.  Comments unrelated to the puzzle at hand, while relevant to the situation here, were not relevant to the *puzzle* here and are being tidied up - they were veering a bit too far into discussion.

Comment: @Patrick, you said you were given 5 of these by a professor, to be solved but not graded; graded or not, the point of "assigning" these is to help you learn to look for facts and apply logic to solving them, not to ask the Internet for the answers.  If you sincerely want help, it's best to provide your progress so far (as you did here) and ask for help in understanding the solving process - so answers focus not on providing the answer, but on *how to find it* instead. I hope we don't shortly see the other 3, but rather see you gain understanding so you can solve the rest yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Hey, guys. Do you know how happy I am right now!!!! I solved it!!

Comment: Congrats! By the way, you can mark this answer (even though it's your own response to yourself) as the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I made sure everything is correct so far. What I am supposed to do next??
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Good progress! Some hints: Rule 8 says that Howell is a man, so if you know something that must be true about any woman, then it cannot also be true for Mr. Howell. Also, Rule 9 says that Adam can't be on the 6th floor; process of elimination will help you out here.

Comment: hi, man. I think I have already gotten things wrong. For Rule 5, I failed. 
Thx for your hints, I will try again

Comment: Hi, man. I just corrected my answer. New progress is posted

Comment: I do not think so. Please take a look at the floors.

Comment: If LINDA is learning English, fifth floor, how can Barbara be even higher since the sixth floor cannot be a woman.

Comment: I see that you have solved it by now, but in case you used a different method, the next step from here would be to match your Xs. For example, at this point, since you know that Julie lives on the first floor & the first floor person can only be named Banes or Gates, you can X out the other possibilities on Julie's row so that only Banes and Gates are left unmarked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't post a comment since I'm new here and lack the reputation, so I hope posting an answer would be ok despite not fully solving the puzzle. I'll try to give minimal hints to help you progress bit by bit, will keep giving more if you get stuck again.

For now: Based on hint #9, Adam will live at a lower floor than Mr Gates. You've deduced that Adam either lives in the 2nd or 4th floor, so there is no way Mr Gates can live in the 1st or 2nd and still fulfill this rule. Addingt his information to your current grid, you can deduce the surname of the person living in the first floor.

Edit: Sadly rule #5 also states that the one surnamed Banes cannot live in the first floor, as Barbara must live lower than them. You've made a mistake in your grid somewhere, I'm afraid.

Comment: You are right, First. based on #5, Barbara lives lower than Banes and Barbara can only live on the third or fifth floor, means Banes cannot live on first second and third floor. We can then know Gates lives on the first floor. Second, based on #9, Adam can not live under the 1st floor.  So, where went wrong